# Probability of predicting, then throwing, a particular multiset for 5 dice.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice, multisets

My friend shared with me a story that after losing to his SO at Yahtzee, before they put the game away he just randomly predicted he would roll four 5's and a 1. He then got that roll and freaked out.

I wanted to calculate exactly how likely that was but my combinatorics knowledge isn't quite strong enough. My question is, for 5 dice, given that the order in which they're thrown doesn't matter, how many possible outcomes are there?

#### My leads and Internet "research"

After a bit of searching it seems that what I'm looking for is combinations with repetition, which led me to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition). So it seems that

$$
\binom {n+k-1} {n-1}
$$

where $n=6$ and $k=5$ would give me the total number of possible rolls...

$$
\binom {6+5-1} {5}=\binom{10}{5}=252
$$

Assuming $252$ is the correct count for the number of possible rolls with 5 dice, this would lead to the probability

$$
{{1}\over{252}}^2 = {1\over63504}
$$

or roughly 0.02% chance of predicting and then throwing a certain multiset of 5 dice.

If someone could verify this or point me in the right direction that would be appreciated. Thank you!

#### Update after Hagen von Eitzen's answer

Hagen von Eitzen made it clear that I actually *don't* want combinations with repetition since not every roll is equally likely. For example, there is one way to roll $\left\{6, 6, 6, 6, 6\right\}$ but five ways to roll $\left\{6, 6, 6, 6, 5\right\}$. Because of this order cannot be discounted. There are a total of $6^5=7776$ ways to roll 5 dice, and the roll predicted by my friend can be thrown in 5 ways, giving it a probability of $5 \over 7776$ of occuring. So the probability of my friend randomly predicting this particular roll and then immediately rolling it is
$$
{5 \over 7776}^2 \approx 0.000041\%
$$

...Hopefully

#### Update after Steven Stadnicki's comments

Steven Stadnicki pointed out to me that the randomness of the guess doesn't play into the probability, leaving the conclusion that the odds of this happening were
$$
{5 \over 7776} \approx 0.064\%
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different outcomes do not have the same probability of $\frac1{252}$. For example "five sixes" has probability $\frac1{6^5}=\frac 1{7776}$.
You can increase your chance of winning by predicting one of the more common outcomes.
For example "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" has a probability of $\frac{24}{3125}$, about twice as much as $\frac1{252}$.

And by the way, your calculation *at best* calculates the probability that someone first predicts one special outcome and then this outcome happens; what you want is that the prediction someone makes comes true.

Comment: Thanks for your input on the first paragraph! However in the second paragraph I don't quite follow what the difference is between making a prediction and then getting that outcome vs. a prediction coming true. Isn't that the same thing?

Comment: For a simple die, your calculation would produce $\frac 1 {6^2}$ (instead of $\frac1{252^2}$). That is the probability that I e.g. randomly pick "3" as prediction and then roll a "3". However, if you play the prediction game with one die, you will notice that the prediction is correct about $\frac16$ of the time, not $\frac1{36}$.

Comment: Oh, wow. The prediction aspect doesn't contribute to the probability anything more than that it specifies one roll. For some reason I was convinced it made the probability smaller to have predicted the roll beforehand. Thank you for explaining! Man, I'm bad at math lol

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, it seems correct to square the probability. He chose his prediction seemingly at random and then rolled it immediately. Doing this with one die, where you make a new random prediction before every roll, you'd have a $1 \over 36$ probability of being successful on any given attempt, right?

Comment: @leo-the-manic Wrong - you would have a 1/6 chance of being successful on any given attempt.  Imagine that instead of making a guess, you open a pre-seeded envelope - or that you guess '1' every time.  Then each time you guess, you have a 1/6 chance of hitting precisely the number you've guessed.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki - but the whole point is that you don't guess '1' every time. If the guess on every roll is random, what's the difference between rolling two dice and seeing if they're the same? One die could be considered the guessing die.

Comment: @leo-the-manic In fact, that was going to be my next example! :-) But think of this: if you roll two dice and see if they're the same, then you have 6 outcomes (1-1, 2-2, ..., 6-6) where they're the same out of your 36 possible rolls, so the probability that the two dice roll the same is 6/36 = 1/6.

Comment: Oh! That is really helpful to point out. It's becoming pretty clear that the fact that it's predicted doesn't end up changing the probability. In the case with two dice, it is easy to calculate that there are 6 ways to come up with pairs from 36 combinations. However for the 5 dice scenario, the 5 original combinations would have to become 38880 in order to maintain probability. Counting this isn't quite clear to me but I can try and figure it out later tonight and perhaps post a follow up question if I can't puzzle it out. Thanks for all of your help!